# C# Modbus frame splitting and storing procedures

Tags: c#, validation, types, bytebuffer, modbus

**The Premise**

I am continually polling custom modbus frames from an embedded device with my c# wpf application at a low interval. At the moment the bytes in the frame i receive are located at the same position every time(e.g. frame[15]+frame[16] = 0x0532 = errorcode2).

**The Questions**

1. Are there smart procedures (other than simply hardcoding the bytestorage) I could use to go from frame receiving to splitting/parsing?
2. What data structures would be preferrable to enable frames to be processed dynamically further down the line?

Answer (score 2):

Method 1:

You can define an explicitly laid out struct in C# and marshal the data to it like is done in the code below.  However, you will have problems with the data due to endian ordering if you are not running on big endian hardware (Modbus data is sent in big endian).  This also won't handle variable length Modbus packets (i.e. Read Input Registers).  NOTE: It is assumed that the frame has already been CRC checked so there is no need to declare and read it.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
struct MyPacket
{
    public Byte Address;        // Byte 0
    public Byte FunctionCode;   // Byte 1
    public Byte ByteField;      // Byte 2
    public UInt32 UInt32Field;  // Bytes 3-6
    public UInt64 UInt64Field;  // Byte 7-14
    public UInt16 ErrorCode;    // Bytes 15-16
}

public static bool TryParse<T>(byte[] array, out T packet) where T : struct
{
    try
    {
        var size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
        var p = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
        Marshal.Copy(array, 0, p, size);
        packet = (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(p, typeof(T));
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(p);
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        packet = default(T);
        return false;
    }
}

static int Main(string[] args)
{
    // Create a sample frame
    byte[] bytes = new byte[] { 0x0, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16 };

    MyPacket packet;

    if (TryParse<MyPacket>(bytes, out packet))
    {
        // Process packet here...
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Method 2:

What I think is a better solution is to define a class for each function type that you use and read each field individually as shown in the code below.  NOTE: It is assumed that the frame has already been CRC checked so there is no need to declare and read it.

```
// VERY SIMPLE BigEndianReader class
public class BigEndianReader
{
    private Stream _stream;

    public BigEndianReader(Stream stream)
    {
        if (stream == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(stream));
        if (!stream.CanRead) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(stream));
        _stream = stream;
    }
    public byte ReadByte()
    {
        int b = _stream.ReadByte();
        if (b < 0) throw new EndOfStreamException();
        return (byte)b;
    }

    public UInt16 ReadUInt16()
    {
        UInt16 v = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(UInt16); i++){v <<= 8;v |= ReadByte();}
        return v;
    }

    public UInt32 ReadUInt32()
    {
        UInt32 v = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(UInt32); i++){v <<= 8;v |= ReadByte();}
        return v;
    }

    public UInt64 ReadUInt64()
    {
        UInt64 v = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(UInt64); i++) { v <<= 8; v |= ReadByte(); }
        return v;
    }
}

class MyPacket
{
    public Byte Address { get; private set; }
    public Byte FunctionCode { get; private set; }
    public Byte ByteField { get; private set; }
    public UInt32 UInt32Field { get; private set; }
    public UInt64 UInt64Field { get; private set; }
    public UInt16 ErrorCode { get; private set; }

    public static bool TryParse(byte[] bytes, out MyPacket result)
    {
        result = null;

        try
        {
            BigEndianReader r = new BigEndianReader(new MemoryStream(bytes));
            MyPacket p = new MyPacket();
            p.Address = r.ReadByte();
            p.FunctionCode = r.ReadByte();
            p.ByteField = r.ReadByte();
            p.UInt32Field = r.ReadUInt32();
            p.UInt64Field = r.ReadUInt64();
            p.ErrorCode = r.ReadUInt16();
            result = p;
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

static int Main(string[] args)
{
    // Create a sample frame
    byte[] bytes = new byte[] { 0x0, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16, 0x17, 0x18, 0x19 };

    MyPacket packet;

    if (MyPacket.TryParse(bytes, out packet))
    {
        // Process packet here...
    }

    //==================================================================
    Console.Write("(press any key to exit)");
    Console.ReadKey(true);
    return 0;
}
```